# How to reference added field in $match?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given this aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      _myVar: "x"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      array: "x"
    }
  }
]
```

How can the field with value `x` only be set once?

For example, this does not work, it times out:

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      _myVar: "x"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$_myVar", "$array"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The variable needs to be available throughout the pipeline, so only using the value in the $match stage as condition is not a solution.

What is the solution?

Comment: Use a function with argument x,and generate the wanted query.I think the "x" is a driver variable,the x will be setted before you send the query.If you dont need _myVar there is not need to add that field,if you only want to check if x is in an array of the document.

Comment: why don't you directly check condition instead of adding field? `{ $match: { array: "x" } }`

Comment: @turivishal Good question, the reason is that the variable needs to be available throughout the pipeline. If I only use the value as condition, it wouldn’t be.

Comment: you can use an external variable in condition, what is the problem you are getting when you use external variable?

Comment: It is not clear, can you share example documents from your collection and your input and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this here i added two fields and checking if _myArray has _myVar,  this is just to explain how can you check... in your case you have to replace _myArray with your actual array against which you want t to match

```
      [{
    $addFields: {
        _myVar: "x",
        _myArray: ['X', 'Y', 'x']
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        has: {
            $in: ["$_myVar", "$_myArray"]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        has: true
    }
}]
```